# Open datasets on medicine/drugs and its uses in treatment

Tags: data-request, medical, drugs

I'm looking for a dataset that contains a list of medicine/drugs and what is it used for.

Example :

```
Medicine        To treat
Paracetamol     Pain 
Paracetamol     Fever
Adderall        Narcolepsy
```

Is there any database that contain a dataset like this with/without using any query ?

Comment: All free sources I know of have this information in free text lists and would require NLP and/or magic to extract. Furthermore, this gets complicated very fast because many drugs have off-label indications.

Answer (score 5):

Check out RxClass from the US National Institute of Health's National Library of Medicine: https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass :

- Example web UI query for all drugs that `may_treat` `FEVER` https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query=Fever|DISEASE&searchBy=class
- This web UI has a SOAP and RESTful API documented at http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/RxClassAPIs.html

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a suitable dataset from Side Effect Resource (SIDER) http://sideeffects.embl.de/ which contain both drug side effect and drug indication. It basically uses Stitch Id for drugs and UMLS Id for diseases in their dataset.

To check stitch id, you can use PubChem to check based on the CID. To check umls id, you can use UMLS Terminology. Since I'm using Python, it's easier to use PubChemPy and UMLS REST Service to get information about the drug.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at

- "[MEDI](https://medschool.vanderbilt.edu/cpm/center-precision-medicine-blog/medi-ensemble-medication-indication-resource) (MEDication Indication) is an ensemble medication indication resource for primary and secondary uses of electronic medical record (EMR) data.  MEDI was created based on multiple commonly used medication resources (RxNorm, MedlinePlus, SIDER 2, and Wikipedia ) and by leveraging both ontology and natural language processing (NLP) techniques."
- "[Hetionet](https://github.com/dhimmel/hetionet): an integrative network of disease — network with multiple node and edge (relationship) types — which encodes biology. The hetnet was designed for Project Rephetio, which aims to systematically identify why drugs work and predict new therapies for drugs." (The drug-disease relationships are assigned a "CtD" type in the network. You need to map drugbank ids to drug names though.)

Answer (score -1):

The [DrugBank](http://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/) website could help